# List comprehension based on a dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I use list comprehension often in Python specifically to create a list from a dictionary of key values, in a sorted manner, I define the sorted keys in a list and use comprehension to get a sorted list, I have been looking around but could not find a similar method of doing the following in Javascript other than using a map:

Is there a better way to do this in Javascript?

In Python:

```
d = {'k2':'v2','k4':'v4','k3':'v3','k6':'v6','k5':'v5'}
list_keys=['k1','k2','k3','k4','k5','k6']

list_wanted_values = [d[c] for c in list_keys]
#list_wanted_values=['v1','v2','v3','v4','v5','v6']
```

In Javascript:

```
var js_list_wanted_values = list_keys.map(function(k){
    js_list_wanted_values[k] = d[k]
)}
```

Comment: just a note for the `python` code: you do not need to define the `list_keys` list. you can just do: `list_wanted_values = [d[c] for c in sorted(d.keys())]` or `list_wanted_values = [v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])]` to avoid the dict lookups

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thanks for the note. This is indeed more elegant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this

```
var js_list_wanted_values = list_keys.map(k => d[k])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should be more like

```
var js_list_wanted_values = list_keys.map(function(k){
    return d[k]
})
```

`map()` creates a new array by returning a new value based on value of each element in array being iterated